# Devise with rails 4 not updating user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I upgraded an app to rails 4 and everything is working fine. I can sign in and goto my edit page. Also updated the views. When using the standard view, the user is updated. But when I add for example the field :name, this is not updated in the form.

Using devise 3.1.1 and also the gem 'protected_attributes'

Do I need to run some kind of update command on devise or db?

I have also searched this place, finding many different solution, but none will update my user field. I have not added any custom fields.

Comment: Have you tried adding the parameter using the rails 4 strong parameters method to see if that passes?

Comment: Setting up strong parameters in application controller worked. The last time I tried it did not, but after I removed the protected_attributes gem and restarted the server, it worked :)

Answer (score 8):

If you want to permit additional parameters you can use a `before filter` in your `ApplicationController` because Rails 4 moved the parameter sanitization from the model to the controller.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :name << :surname << :username
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :name << :surname << :username
  end
end
```

You can also find more [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters).

Comment: Is there a difference between that and `devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }`